# How do I workaround datetime2's explicit conversion policy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I created a report a while ago which is used to return data from an Audit table which gathers login and logout activity on a trading platform.

I began to have issues with a certain string following the implementation of `datetime2` datatypes one the date columns. Specifically the string was used to gather various bits of information about how active a user was during a given month, being used to denote their number of logins and logouts, the number of days they were active for before logging out following a log in etc etc.

```
CAST(MAX(FLOOR(CAST(bus.SessionTimestamp AS FLOAT))) AS DATETIME) as SessionDate
```

The issues are due to the conversion of `datetime2` to `float` no longer being an option, as `datetime` used to be.

How can I get the above string to work in a similar way but actually function properly again?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: what is the datatype of bus.SessionTimeStamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you realise what this code is trying to do, it's a trivial conversion:

```
MAX(CAST(bus.SessionTimestamp AS DATE)) as SessionDate
```

The `FLOOR` after converting to `float` is just removing the time component. Up to you whether you reinstate the `CAST` back to `datetime2` after computing the `MAX`.

Comment: Thank you, I think i was looking too hard at this and failing to see the simple answer. I appreciate it.